# Disable F5 and browser refresh using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to disable browser refreshing using JavaScript.

Currently, I am using `window.onbeforeunload` and I don't want it to be called when user refreshes the browser.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

*Update* A recent comment claims this doesn't work in the new Chrome ... As shown in jsFiddle, and tested on my personal site, this method still works as of Chrome ver `26.0.1410.64 m`

This is REALLY easy in jQuery by the way:

### jsFiddle

```
// slight update to account for browsers not supporting e.which
function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) e.preventDefault(); };
// To disable f5
    /* jQuery < 1.7 */
$(document).bind("keydown", disableF5);
/* OR jQuery >= 1.7 */
$(document).on("keydown", disableF5);

// To re-enable f5
    /* jQuery < 1.7 */
$(document).unbind("keydown", disableF5);
/* OR jQuery >= 1.7 */
$(document).off("keydown", disableF5);
```

On a side note:
    This only disables the f5 button on the keyboard.
    To truly disable refresh you must use a server side script to check for page state changes.
    Can't say I really know how to do this as I haven't done it yet.

On the software site that I work at,  we use my disableF5 function in conjunction with Codeigniter's session data.  For instance, there is a lock button which will lock the screen and prompt a password dialog.  The function "disableF5" is quick and easy and keeps that button from doing anything.  However, to prevent the mouse-click on refresh button, a couple things take place.

1. When lock is clicked, user session data has a variable called "locked" that becomes TRUE
2. When the refresh button is clicked, on the master page load method is a check against session data for "locked", if TRUE, then we simple don't allow the redirect and the page never changes, regardless of requested destination

---

***TIP:*** Try using a server-set cookie, such as PHP's `$_SESSION`, or even .Net's `Response.Cookies`, to maintain "where" your client is in your site. This is the more *Vanilla* way to do what I do with CI's Session class. The big difference being that CI uses a Table in your DB, whereas these *vanilla* methods store an editable cookie in the client. The downside though, is a user can clear its cookies.

Comment: Hello dear, You code is really great I try in my one of page and it's disable all autopostback for my all control on that page. After that I remove these line of code. But autopostback not enable. I restart my machine clear all browser history but autopostback not enable at all. What is reason behind that. Please guide me.

Comment: @alem0lars after extensive testing, i found this function still works in Chrome just fine. perhaps we can see some of your other code? [See working example in Chrome HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/C85Hs/). As you can see it works fine and your Down vote was really unnecessary.

Comment: This is really cool, but I have a question. `Ctrl+Shift+R` is for hard reload, similarly `Ctrl+R` or `F5` is for normal reload. I have seen some sites give the option to do all of them after **long press of the reload button**. Yes we can block these keys, but how can we block that menu from popping for a specific site/page?

Comment: You'll probably also want to add cases for Ctrl+F5 and Ctrl+R.
Also, most browsers allow refreshing from the context menu. Not much you can do here besides disabling the context menu all together, which in most cases is something to avoid.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't disable refreshing at all. It merely blocks the F5 key, if the document has focus. Saying "This is REALLY easy in jQuery" is disingenuous at best.

Answer (score 11):

```
var ctrlKeyDown = false;

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(document).on("keydown", keydown);
    $(document).on("keyup", keyup);
});

function keydown(e) { 

    if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116 || ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 82 && ctrlKeyDown)) {
        // Pressing F5 or Ctrl+R
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 17) {
        // Pressing  only Ctrl
        ctrlKeyDown = true;
    }
};

function keyup(e){
    // Key up Ctrl
    if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 17) 
        ctrlKeyDown = false;
};
```

Answer (score 11):

Enter this simple script in pure JS:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.keyCode == 116){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: combined with || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 82) this is by far the simplest solution proposed

Answer (score 9):

From the site Enrique posted:

```
window.history.forward(1);
document.attachEvent("onkeydown", my_onkeydown_handler);
function my_onkeydown_handler() {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 116 : // 'F5'
            event.returnValue = false;
            event.keyCode = 0;
            window.status = "We have disabled F5";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, this doesn't disable the `Back Button`. The 1st line [`window.history.forward(1);`] is meant to be put on EVERY page you don't want user to go `back` to. Simply put, if user hits back, they are redirected to were they are. This really only works with `linear sequence` pages, such as banking sign ins. The rest is just Vanilla JS of the jQuery Method I spoke of in my answer. Most places have replaced the first line with either a server side redirect, or something like Node.JS which allows for *live calls*, like sockets, keeping constant *tabs* on what the user is doing. Much easier

Answer (score 7):

for mac cmd+r, cmd+shift+r to need.

```
function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116 || (e.which || e.keyCode) == 82) e.preventDefault(); };

$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("keydown", disableF5);
});
```

Comment: `(e.which || e.keyCode) == 82)` is also true when just pressing `r` alone on a Mac.  So if you have a textbox you won't be able to enter `r`.

Comment: this disables the key 'r'

Answer (score 6):

Use this for modern browsers:

```
function my_onkeydown_handler( event ) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 116 : // 'F5'
            event.preventDefault();
            event.keyCode = 0;
            window.status = "F5 disabled";
            break;
    }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", my_onkeydown_handler);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the code I'm using to disable refresh on IE and firefox which works for the following key combinations:

<kbd>F5</kbd>   |  
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>   |  
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

```js
//this code handles the F5/Ctrl+F5/Ctrl+R
document.onkeydown = checkKeycode
function checkKeycode(e) {
    var keycode;
    if (window.event)
        keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e)
        keycode = e.which;
                
    // Mozilla firefox
    if ($.browser.mozilla) {
        if (keycode == 116 ||(e.ctrlKey && keycode == 82)) {
            if (e.preventDefault)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
    } 
    // IE
    else if ($.browser.msie) {
        if (keycode == 116 || (window.event.ctrlKey && keycode == 82)) {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
            window.event.keyCode = 0;
            window.status = "Refresh is disabled";
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use useragent to detect what type of browser it is (`$.browser` uses `navigator.userAgent` to determine the platform), you can use

`if('MozBoxSizing' in document.documentElement.style)` which returns true for firefox

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to separate questions. If the questions are duplicates, flag one as a duplicate of the other (or leave a comment to that effect). Otherwise, please tailor your answer to the question asked.

Comment: but what if user clicks the refresh button

Answer (score 5):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) { 
    return "Unloading this page may lose data. What do you want to do..."
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't event make sense. You have unreachable code after the return point.

Comment: It kind of works for me on firefox, but not chrome. Feel like this could be a more useful answer if elaborated on to robustly work.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me in all the browsers:

```
document.onkeydown = function(){
  switch (event.keyCode){
        case 116 : //F5 button
            event.returnValue = false;
            event.keyCode = 0;
            return false;
        case 82 : //R button
            if (event.ctrlKey){ 
                event.returnValue = false;
                event.keyCode = 0;
                return false;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable ctrl+f5 , ctrl+R , f5 ,backspace then you can use this simple code. This code is working in Mozila as well as Chrome . Add this code inside your body tag:

```
<body onkeydown="return (event.keyCode == 154)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use hotkey from rich faces if you are using JSF.

```
<rich:hotKey key="backspace" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 8) return false;" handler="return false;" disableInInput="true" />
<rich:hotKey key="f5" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 116) return false;" handler="return false;" disableInInput="true" />
<rich:hotKey key="ctrl+R" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 123) return false;" handler="return false;" disableInInput="true" />
<rich:hotKey key="ctrl+f5" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 154) return false;" handler="return false;" disableInInput="true" />
```