# How do I disable the F5 refresh on the browser?

Tags: javascript, refresh

Preferably using JavaScript but would like to hear other ways too

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  I ask because it's an unusual thing to want to do, and there may be a better way to solve your underlying problem.

Comment: You can only do it by disabling F5. I googled "Disable F5 Refresh" and got quite enough searches to figure it out quickly.

Comment: If you disable my `F5`, I'll try `CTRL+W` or `ALT+F4` next.

Comment: Hi eric,

I have a button on a screen that sends a web service. if i hit this button, and then hit F5, its going to send that web service twice.

Thanks

Comment: @RoboShop: I would have the page send a unique token (randomly generated when you render the HTML page) along with the web service request.  If it gets that token a second time, assume refresh was pressed and discard the request.

Comment: Also see question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482059/disable-f5-and-browser-refresh-using-javascript

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will disable F5, but not the actual refresh function:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 116) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

On Chrome/XP, at least.

Comment: I hit the refresh button more often than I hit F5. If a user has just clicked one button, they might be more likely to click another button rather than hit a key.

Answer (score 10):

1. Write a series of **browser extensions**
   which remove refresh functionality.
2. Require in your **Terms of Use** that
   your users install (and use) your extension.
3. **Prosecute** for non-compliance.
4. Profit! (?)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can.. This little routine fixed it all for me..

I needed the other shortcuts, but not F5.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then WebBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = False Else WebBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = True
End Sub
```

Quick and dirty, but it works.
Now, I can still use the Ctrl-B, I and U for editing, but I don't have to worry about refresh killing it!!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable refresh.

Comment: that wasn't the question. The question was to disable the "F5" refresh

Comment: @RoboShop - I thought that was implied in my answer, though it looks like Matt has proved me wrong.