# Disable F5 in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, browser

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Disable browser's back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961188/disable-browsers-back-button)
>   [How do I disable the F5 refresh on the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918061/how-do-i-disable-the-f5-refresh-on-the-browser)

Hi,

I created an application in C# that will download data from the internet (and this is done one time only) and put it in a webbrowser and this data should be static. I want to know if there is a way to disable the F5 key from doing a refresh?

I tried injecting javascript to disable F5 but it will still refresh the webbrowser.

Comment: also there are many similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=disable+refresh+browser

Comment: I can't cast a vote to reopen, but I would if I could.  This question is asking about disabling F5 in a `WebBrowser` control, which the 'possible duplicates' do **not** address.

Comment: I don't really know why this is a duplicate entry. This is using WebBrowser control on a Windows Form.

Comment: Voted to re-open, it's unique from the other questions for the reasons stated by the two commenters above.

Comment: I'd vote for a reopen if I could as well.  The duplicates listed aren't at all related to WebBrowserControl... Did anyone ever figure out a solution that would allow for CTRL+C to still work?

Comment: I would also vote to reopen question as this refers to a WebBrowser control which none of the other questions seem to.  The question could be made clearer.

Comment: As an aside, I managed to solve this problem by handling the previewKeyDown event and looking for f5 and setting event.handled to true

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot disable F5 (or other browser shortcut keys) via JavaScript.

Setting the `WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled` property of the `WebBrowser` control to `false` should accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Got a problem. It disables keyboard shortcuts but also disables links that will open IE.

Comment: Handle the `WebBrowser.Navigating` event: `private void WebBrowserNavigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e) { if (e.Url.ToString() != "about:blank") { System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Url.ToString()); e.Cancel=true; } }`

Comment: Windows acts weird. Tried pressing F5 continuously then clicking a link but it will not respond to it. But, if you say you put MessageBox onClick event, it will respond to it.

Comment: Quick warning, this disables all shortcut keys, so no Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V etc...

Comment: If anyone is struggling with the lack of Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V, I just posted up some sample code to get around this, you can find it here: http://blog.intninety.co.uk/2012/08/disable-shortcuts-in-webbrowser-control-and-keep-copy-and-paste/ Hope this helps anyone else who may be stuck with it!

Comment: As mentioned by a few people setting WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled to false will indeed stop ALL shortcuts from working, which is far from ideal.  Btw, the link provided by rastating doesn't work!

Comment: rastating's link is available in the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20130414212547/http://blog.intninety.co.uk/2012/08/disable-shortcuts-in-webbrowser-control-and-keep-copy-and-paste/

Answer (score -1):

call this function on the onKeyDown event

```
 document.onkeydown = function(e) {
      // keycode for F5 function
      if (e.keyCode === 116) {
        return false;
      }
      // keycode for backspace
      if (e.keyCode === 8) {
        // try to cancel the backspace
        return false;
      }
    };
```

This will prevent from F5 reload and backspace back.

Comment: this doesn't work. I tried this by injecting in webbrowser. On normal html this will work.

Comment: @Azhar where did you add the onkeydown event.  It's not exposed by WebBrowser or WebBrowser.Document.  I tried it on the parent form and it isn't invoked on keypresses.