# WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled equivalent in wpf WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to stop `F5` on my `WebBrowser control` in `WPF`. I have came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4011450/2470362).  but i am unable to find `WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled` for `WebBrowser control`. Is there an equivalent for `WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled` or am i missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may prevent keyboard events from reaching the `WebBrowser` control in WPF by handling its `PreviewKeyDown` event. This will allow you to override the behavior, as well as do nothing for specific key strokes. Handling the Backspace key might be harder, since it might prevent user input in text boxes.

```
void Browser_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F5)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<WebBrowser PreviewKeyDown="Browser_OnPreviewKeyDown"></WebBrowser>
```

Comment: Hope i need an Attached Property :)