# how to detect an F5 refresh keypress event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I noticed that jquery has a keypress function. But it seems that it can only detect keypress event of numbers and characters. It cannot detect the F5 keypress event. And What surprises me the most is everyone online says that the keyCode of F5 is 116, But when I use the jquery keypress function, it just shows that the character t has the keyCode of 116(it seems that 116 is the ascii code of lowercase t)! Can somebody give me any idea about this and how to detect the F5 event in javascript or jquery? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: I don't think any browser would let you catch events for Function button presses...

Comment: @SidharthMudgal - [Why not](http://jsfiddle.net/Brjb2/)

Comment: you don't think  `location.reload();` is same as 'F5'

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/7997282/1264846

Comment: By the time you've detected it, it would be to late anyway as the page will reload, and you could just as well have used `onbeforeunload` ?

Comment: this is workable soultion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser

Comment: please see the link. It might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707602/capturing-f5-keypress-event-in-javascript-using-window-event-keycode-in-window-o?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keypress event does not accept function keys(F1-F12). You can try to use keydown event.

Comment: Exactly right. More specifically "keypress" refers to the event where something is typed. If the button you press would cause something to happen in a textarea, then the `keypress` event fires. `keydown`, however, fires for all keys.

Comment: The 'keypress' will be fired repeat if you hold one normal key, however the 'keydown' will be fired only one time for each keystroke.

Comment: That's for the same reason as it firing in the first place. Its frequency depends on the keyboard settings.

Comment: Yes. This topic can refer JS Event model/order at here http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you did wrong in your code, but jQuery does say `F5` is `116` and `t` is `84`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Brjb2/1

One possible error is `keypress` will have different `keycode`, that's why `keydown` is more preferred.

```
        |  T  |  A  |  F5
keydown |  86 |  65 | 116
keypress| 116 |  97 |  -
```

Also pressing `F5` will not trigger `keypress` because the reload part happens before `keypress`.

Answer (score 1):

this code works good for me

i tested it in chrome and firefox successfully

```
<script>
    document.onkeydown = capturekey;
    document.onkeypress = capturekey;
    document.onkeyup = capturekey;

    function capturekey(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        //debugger
        if (e.code == 'F5') {
            if (confirm('do u wanna to refresh??')) {
                //allow to refresh
            } 
            else {
                //avoid from refresh
                e.preventDefault()
                e.stopPropagation()
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```