# capturing f5 keypress event in javascript using window.event.keyCode in window.onbeforeunload event is always 0 and not 116

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am creating an MVC application.There was a neccessitity to make a variable in a session to null upon closing of the application (i.e. window/tab) but not upon refreshing the application. 
I tried it through the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
               e = e || window.event;
               if (window.event.keyCode == 116) {
                   alert("f5 pressed");
               }
               else {
                   alert("Window closed");
                   //call my c# code to make my variable null, eg:Session["myVariable"] = null;
               }  
           };
</script>
```

But when F5 is pressed then, "window.event.keyCode" is always 0 and not 116.
Because of which my variable is becoming null even upon F5 key press which is not my requirement.

Even when the application (i.e. webpage) is closed,even then its 0 (which is probably correct).

Please note that the above part of the code is in .cshtml file.

Can anyone tell where am i wrong ?

Comment: you are storeing your event into the variable e. Why don't you try `e.keyCode` ;) And the event you should listen to is the keyPress event.

Comment: hi meo: i already have tried it but i get the same result. Then i tried the above mentioned code, but still in **vain**.

Comment: You cant set Session variables in javascript...

Comment: If you are looking to do session stuff client side, maybe you should look at sessvars.js http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html

Comment: Doesn't `e.keyCode` apply only to keyboard events? (Also, even if it did apply, you should test `e.keyCode` in your `if` statement, not `window.event.keyCode`.)

Comment: @Steve: Thanks, you are right, i just wanted to show the sample so i did that way. but now i have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: F5 is not the only way a user can refresh the page...

Comment: @Juhana: yes, user can also use Ctrl + R, but first i was not able to capture F5 itself which is most obvious way. If i could then i will also add condition for "Ctrl + R".

Comment: What are you going to do about clicking the reload button?

Comment: Final conclusion: (i am adding this comment as it could be helpful to others). the **"window.event.keyCode"** is always **0** by the time the code control reaches **"window.onbeforeunload"**.So please use it wisely.

Comment: Actually there is a way to set a session variable from javascript , and that's to call a controller method via jS that does that. I've done it before. (sorry if too late or a bit off topic)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to listen to different events if you want this to work crossborwser + you have to listen to the key-event every time its pressed, not on load:

```
document.onkeydown = fkey;
document.onkeypress = fkey
document.onkeyup = fkey;

var wasPressed = false;

function fkey(e){
        e = e || window.event;
       if( wasPressed ) return; 

        if (e.keyCode == 116) {
             alert("f5 pressed");
            wasPressed = true;
        }else {
            alert("Window closed");
        }
 }
```

here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FSrgV/1/embedded/result/

but if you simply want to know if the user quits the page you could simply use `window.onbeforeunload`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: Hi **meo**: Thanks for you answer, it helped me with some modification. :)

Comment: I used this modification in Oracle ADF. Thanks.

Comment: When I go with my Firefox browser to http://jsfiddle.net/FSrgV/1/embedded/result/ and I pressed F5 then, I see no alert or something...

Comment: dont use (e.keyCode == 116) to ckeck F5  ;  instead of use this

Comment: if (e.code == 'F5')      { // your code here 
           
        }

Answer (score 11):

Dont use `e.keyCode == 116` use `e.keyCode == 'F5'` instead.

```
 function fkey(e){
    e = e || window.event;
   if( wasPressed ) return; 

    function fkey(e){
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.code === 'F5') {
            alert("f5 pressed");
            wasPressed = true;
        }else {
            alert("Window closed");
        }
    }
```

This is because the 't' and 'F5' both use the keycode number 116. If you go on keycode alone then if the user presses the 't' key your page will refresh.

Comment: This is most definitely not the case. F5 is 116. T is 84.

Comment: @Adowrath On some browsers and systems F5 and 'T' 100% return 116 as the keycode.

Answer (score 4):

You could just write it like this:

```
$(document.body).on("keydown", this, function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 116) {
        alert('F5 pressed!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.onkeydown = disableF5;
document.onkeypress = disableF5
document.onkeyup = disableF5;    
function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) e.preventDefault(); };
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified version and working also after pressing 't'.

key 116 getting pressed auto after 84

```
document.onkeydown = fkey;
document.onkeypress = fkey
document.onkeyup = fkey;

var wasPressed = false;

function fkey(e){
    e = e || window.event;
   if( wasPressed ) return; 

    if (e.keyCode == 116) {
         alert("f5 pressed");

    }else {
        alert("Window closed");
    }
    wasPressed = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

dont use (e.keyCode == 116) to ckeck F5 ; instead of use this

```
<script>
    document.onkeydown = capturekey;
    document.onkeypress = capturekey;
    document.onkeyup = capturekey;

    function capturekey(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        //debugger
        if (e.code == 'F5') {
            if (confirm('do u wanna to refresh??')) {
                //allow to refresh
            } 
            else {
                //avoid from refresh
                e.preventDefault()
                e.stopPropagation()
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with meo's solution, but I will add some modifications.

when we use document.onkeydown = fkey; for example and in the page we have another method affected to the document.onkeydown then the browser will detect only the last event.
However when we use :
jQuery(document).on("keydown",fkey); even if we have another function to handle the keydown event, all the functions will be triggered.

see the next example to more understand:

```
var wasPressed = false;
document.onkeydown = f1;
document.onkeydown = f2;

jQuery(document).on("keydown",f3); 
jQuery(document).on("keydown",f4); 
function f1(e){
e = e || window.event;
if( wasPressed ) return; 

        if (e.keyCode == 116) {
             alert("f5 pressed");
            wasPressed = true;
        }else {
            alert("Window closed");
        }
}
function f2(){
    alert('f2');
}
function f3(){
    alert('f3');
}
function f4(){
    alert('f4');
}
```

what will be shown here: only 3 alerts: f2,f3 and f4. and the f1 function isn't triggred in this example.