# jquery client side validation not working as expected when page refreshed [F5]

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following function for client side validation:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            document.onkeydown = function () {
                if (event.keyCode == 116) {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    event.returnValue = false;
                }
            }


            $("#btnEnviar").click(function () {

                $("#cerrarPopup").click(addHandlerCloseModal);

                var msg = "";
                if ($("#txtNombre").val() == "") { msg += "El nombre es un campo obligatorio <br/>"; };
                if ($("#txtTelefono").val() == "" ||
                   !$.isNumeric($("#txtTelefono").val()) ||
                    $("#txtTelefono").val().length != 9) {
                    msg += "Introduzca un teléfono válido de 9 posiciones. <br/>";
                };

                if (msg != "") {
                    doModal(msg);
                    return false;
                }

                if (!$('#chkClausulas').prop("checked")) {
                    msg = "No ha aceptado las condiciones legales";
                    doModal(msg);
                    return false;
                }

                //$("#span1").html('');

                return true;
            });

        });

        function doModal(obj) {
            $("#spanMsg").each(function () {
                $(this).html(obj);
            });
            $("#divModal").modal();
        }

        function clearForm() {
            $("#rightContent input:text").val('');
            $('#chkClausulas').attr("checked", false);
        }

        function addHandlerCloseModal() {           
                $.modal.close();           
        }

    </script>
```

And then, in server side validation I process the request and show a modal message that confirms the request has been successful.

```
Dim msgScript As String = "<script type='text/javascript'>" & _
        "$('#span1').html('');clearForm();doModal('#msg#'); " & _
         "$('#cerrarPopup').click(function () { $.modal.close(); }); " &
        "</script>"

  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "doModal", _
                                        msgScript.Replace("#msg#", outMsg), False)
```

This is working as expected. The client gets the Processed message and the clearForm();
function clears all the input:text controls.

The problem is when you press refresh button at browsert, or F5, or CTRL + F5 the
form is submitted again with previous values although the forms has been cleared.

I used this:

```
   document.onkeydown = function () {
                if (event.keyCode == 116) {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    event.returnValue = false;
                }
            }
```

To avoid F5 key press but it is not working all the time.

How can I avoid the form re-submission. Why is the browser caching text input values
although the controls are being cleared?

Comment: That is a common behavior on asp.net forms sites because each interaction is a server POST. When you refresh the browser tries to refresh the last action which sadly is a POST.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand the problem, in any case, have you tried to put a check when the page loads the server side?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Because I do not need to check the page load. It is not loading anything. The problem is that the F5 is firing the send button

Comment: Can I help this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707602/capturing-f5-keypress-event-in-javascript-using-window-event-keycode-in-window-o ?