# How to use keydown event in jquery without affecting all keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, page-refresh, onkeydown

I should prevent page refresh using pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. I prepare following code to reach this aim, but when I press any key in the page the function is running and can't fill any textbox or press any other keys in the page. How can I solve this problem?

```
      $(" * ").bind('keydown', 'F5', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        abp.message.confirm("Are You Sure To Refresh This Page?",
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    window.location = "NewForm?id=" + $("#Id").val();
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [capturing f5 keypress event in javascript using window.event.keyCode in window.onbeforeunload event is always 0 and not 116](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707602/capturing-f5-keypress-event-in-javascript-using-window-event-keycode-in-window-o)

Comment: Check this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482059/disable-f5-and-browser-refresh-using-javascript

Comment: @DhanushkaDolapihilla I can't use this manner, because when F5 is pressed I want to confirm user, and I should preventDefault event action and in this Time the event will be run.

Comment: @Azad, can you include that and complete what you are trying to achieve in the question, with better clarity.

Comment: @DhanushkaDolapihilla I updated it.

Comment: @Azad Asking some unclear question and spamming around the same comment doesn't look so good in this community. And the people trying to help you shouldn't have to follow up with all the answers and comments to figure out what exactly you want.

Comment: Still not clear enough. Tell me if i got it. 
1. When F5 is pressed, you want to block refresh, and prompt user to confirm the refresh using your code mentioned here.
2. All the other keys should work without affecting your inputs etc. 

also, 

`$(" * ").bind('keydown', 'F5', function (e)` this would not catch the F5 keydown. rather check if `e.keyCode == 116` as suggested in many answers

Comment: @DhanushkaDolapihilla Yse, exactly. My goal is what you said in your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Azad, Well, Don't you think, it should be mentioned there in your question? :)

Answer (score 3):

Correct keyCode for <kbd>F5</kbd> is **116**:

```js
    $(function () {  
        $(document).keydown(function (e) {  
             if((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116){
              if(confirm("Your confirmation message...")){
                 e.preventDefault(); 
              }
             }
        });  
    });
```

```html
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</body>
```

***Added for the sake of completeness***

Could combine `e.ctrlKey` to detect the press of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> combination. Looks something like

```
if (evtobj.keyCode == 116 && evtobj.ctrlKey) alert("Ctrl+F5");
```

Found [this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29sVC/).

Comment: I can't use this manner, because when F5 is pressed I want to confirm user, and I should preventDefault event action and in this Time the event will be run.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to identify F5 function key event, for which you need the key codes.

If you refer [here](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes), the key code for **F5** is **116**.

Since you are trying to disable the document event, you need to add bind an event on key down of the document.

```
$(document).on("keydown", disableRefresh);

function disableRefresh(event){
   if(event.keyCode == 116){
     if confirm("whatever you want to confirm"){
       event.preventDefault(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: I can't use this manner, because when F5 is pressed I want to confirm user, and I should preventDefault event action and in this Time the event will be run

Comment: @Azad Edited as per your comment

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.d = function(log) {
  $('#console').text(log);
}

var callback = function(e) {
  console.log(e.type, e);
  var text = e.type;
  var code = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if (13 === code) {
    text += ': ENTER';
  } else {
    text += ': keycode ' + code;
  }
  console.d(text);
};

$('#input').keydown(callback);
$('#input').keypress(callback);
$('#input').keyup(callback);

$('.keydown').click(function(e) {
  var code = $(this).data('code');
  $('#input').trigger(
    jQuery.Event('keydown', {
      keyCode: code,
      which: code
    })
  );
});
$('.keypress').click(function(e) {
  var code = $(this).data('code');
  $('#input').trigger(
    jQuery.Event('keypress', {
      keyCode: code,
      which: code
    })
  );
});
$('.keyup').click(function(e) {
  var code = $(this).data('code');
  $('#input').trigger(
    jQuery.Event('keyup', {
      keyCode: code,
      which: code
    })
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><label>input: <input type="text" name="foo" id="input" value="" /></label></p>

<p>
  <button class="keydown" data-code="13">Trigger keydown Enter</button>
  <button class="keypress" data-code="13">Trigger keypress Enter</button>
  <button class="keyup" data-code="13">Trigger keyup Enter</button>
</p>

<p>
  <button class="keydown" data-code="65">Trigger keydown 'a'</button>
  <button class="keypress" data-code="65">Trigger keypress 'a'</button>
  <button class="keyup" data-code="65">Trigger keyup 'a'</button>
</p>

<hr />

<div id="console"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the looks of the question and certain comments (your requirement is not clearly mentioned in the question), I suppose this is what you should do.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function (e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 116 || (e.keyCode == 116 && e.ctrlKey)){
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default bevaior only if F5 or Ctrl+F5 [thanks to the first two commenters (y) :)]
            //This is from your original post
            abp.message.confirm("Are You Sure To Refresh This Page?",
                function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        window.location = "NewForm?id=" + $("#Id").val();
                    }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hunxdftv/16/) out, to see this in action.

Comment: "when I press any key in the page the function is running and can't fill any textbox or press any other keys in the page" 
Your answer would still give OP this problem right. Mainly because all the keydowns will call their preventDefault

Comment: @RomeoSierra You prevent the default behavior in first line of your function without specifying any key. So the function prevents all key down actions.

Comment: @DhanushkaDolapihilla, @Azad, That's my bad I didn't notice it in the first place. It should actually go inside the `if` block to check the event's keycode. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```html
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 116){
         e.preventDefault();
         alert("Hello!");
         return false;
    }
})
```