# detect browser close by js and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, server

**how to code a code to detect when user is close their browser and show up a pop up message ? but if press F5 or move to other page ,dont let it work , only work when browser closing**

Comment: If you want to do this by JS / Jquery as your title suggest, why have you tagged it with php? - Further more, "Doesn't work" isn't a very informative problem statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Close windows event by Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707249/detect-close-windows-event-by-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because JavaScript runs within your browser. So it cannot detect your click closing the browser.

However it is possible to check if `F5` was pressed, but this was not your main aim. [how to detect an F5 refresh keypress event in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872853/how-to-detect-an-f5-refresh-keypress-event-in-jquery)