# How to run function after press F5 (refresh)?

Tags: javascript, events, refresh, dom-events

I tried to make some script that handle with event like "panel changes follow by URLhash". I had no problem with event on button or link but I had problem when I refreshed the page. My panel couldn't keep its values and automatically reset.

And I tried to solve refresh problem like this:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 116) {
        window.alert("1234");
        var id = window.location.hash;
        changePanel(id);
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

As code I shown you, `alert()` function it was working, but `changePanel()`  wasn't working. I think because `alert()` had ran before refreshed and `changePanel()` also. But in case of `changePanel()` it ran before refresh then after refreshed all changes are reset to default.

How to run `changePanel()` after refresh?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482059/disable-f5-and-browser-refresh-using-javascript (use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent refresh)

Answer (score 0):

It will not work, because after press of `f5` page will be refreshed so new content will come  on page, and so your panel/tab is reset..

You can try your code on

```
$(document).ready(
     var id = window.location.hash;
     changePanel(id);
);
```

Above code will automatically set tab after refresh button, and you can keep same code of that 2 lines on your button press, so that will work for your live page too. :)

This will work for you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly for me.

Call the funtion from your html

```
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="loro()">fdthd</button>
```

JS file

```
function loro() {
  location.reload();
  localStorage.setItem("po", "momo");
}

$(window).on("load", function() {
if (localStorage.getItem("po") === "momo" ) {
  alert('Bien, ejecutaste el boton')
  localStorage.setItem("po", "lulu");
} else {
  alert('No has precionado el boton')
}

});
```

Before refresh the page I run a Function to save the "momo" value in the "po"key
After that, I refresh the page and check if PO has the value of momo. Depending on if I run the function before the refresh, it will run a specific alert.