# Block/disable F5-/CTRL-R in Internet Explorer within Flash context

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer

I'm trying to block *F5* and *CTRL-R* in the Internet Explorer while displaying a Flash-Application. It works by using the Javascript *onkeydown*-event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536938(v=vs.85).aspx). But at the moment I click somewhere in the Flash application it won't work anymore.

Is there any chance to block/disable those keys even in the Flash context, maybe without using an external library?

Unfortunately the *onbeforeunload*-event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't fit for me because I have to reload the page by code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add the URL of the site you’re implementing this on? Just so I know to *never visit it*.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482059/disable-f5-and-browser-refresh-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I tried these solutions yet. Unfortunately they are not working for me. Once I click into the running Flash application and press F5 after that, the page will refresh.