# Angularjs: capture the refresh event in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In angularjs is possible handle the user clicking the Refresh button on the browser?
There is any method that the framework expose to the developer?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you intend to "handle". But a quick Google search lists the following discussions:

1. Info on Angular $routeProvider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324902/how-does-angular-application-handle-refresh-page-and-could-we-use-history-on-lo

2. Disabling refreshes:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482059/disable-f5-and-browser-refresh-using-javascript

3. Handle route events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344223/angularjs-cancel-route-change-event

Answer (score 7):

To handle the reload itself (which includes hitting F5) and to take action before it reloads or even cancel, use 'beforeunload' event.

```
var windowElement = angular.element($window);
windowElement.on('beforeunload', function (event) {
   //Do Something

   //After this will prevent reload or navigating away.
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$routeChageStart`:

```
 $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
            alert('refresh');
        });
```

Comment: As far as I know, this is not what OP asked for. This event fires every time the view is changed, not specially on user refresh.

Comment: Though the answer is wrong, it does not deserve a negative penalty

Comment: I don't think this would work; the `beforeunload` is pretty tough on accepting changes in behaviour from javascript. e.g. with angular 7 the *somehow* equivalent approach with `canDeactivate` doesn't work.