# Message for reloading a webpage

Tags: javascript, reload

I want to prevent users from reloading the page each time to get updated dynamic content. So I have used this code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return "Dont need to reload the whole page. Just reload the section";
    }
```

It's working fine except when an user closes the browser's tab/window, the same message is showing also. But I want to show the message only for reloading/F5 button, not for closing the browser's tab/window. What event handler should I have to used for that purpose?

Comment: This is an extremely FAQ.

Comment: sorry but could not understand what you have replied mplungjan

Comment: http://bit.ly/15AI6V1

Comment: He's saying that this question is asked a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identifying Between Refresh And Close Browser Actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can physically disable the f5 button, to get functionality similar to what you want:

[Disable F5 and browser refresh using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482059/disable-f5-and-browser-refresh-using-javascript)

Comment: lol...mplungjan..He did not mean physically as to destroy F5 button of keyboard. He meant it by code. You should not voted it down.