# how to call doPost method when the webaddress is refreshed

Tags: servlets

I have observed that when the address in the address bar is selected and an enter key is pressed,the doGet method is invoked and not the doPost method.
How to invoke the doPost method ,and not doGet.

Comment: follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482059/disable-f5-and-browser-refresh-using-javascript

Comment: i want to prevent the refresh,when I click on  the address bar and then press enter?(not only the F5 ,ctrl+R)?

Answer (score 0):

add this in your doGet() method

```
doPost(request,response);
```

and it will work

Comment: I see that the doPost gets invoked from doGet method,but when I access the parameters from doPost using 'request.getparameter(),i am getting null values.

Comment: post your doGet() method please

Comment: this is my doGet :                                              public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
  doPost(request,response);
 }

Comment: have you tried like String name=request.getParameter("name");

Comment: In doPost I have these type of commands.And they work fine if I am directly submitting the form by clicking the submit button.But the problem comes after I submit the form,if I click on the address bar and press enter.As I mentioned earlier if I invoke doPost from doGet,the String name=request.getParameter("name"); is returning null.

Comment: remove method parameter from your form tag and then try clicking on the URL ,

Comment: so you are suggesting to write the code in doPost to doGet?but i am passing  lot of values (URL length will become 3500+) ,in that case doGet is not working.

Comment: ,any other suggestion?