# Disable F5 (Refresh) in a flex application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I have a flex application with multiple tabs. If a user moves to the second tab, I need to disable the F5 (Refresh) key. How can I do it for IE?

I am not able to catch an event in case of F5, browser catches its first and refreshes the whole application. I don't want that to happen.

I guess IE runs a flash application as activex and in IE F5 key is not passed to activex, this is because I am facing such a problem. Is it correct?

Any solution?

Comment: Please give sample code

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from javascript. Stop the browser refresh as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482059/disable-f5-and-browser-refresh-using-javascript) and [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Disable-F5-Key-Button-and-browser-refresh-using-JavaScript-or-jQuery.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

add keydown event listener in your html file such like:

```
function (e):{
    if (e.keycode == keyboard.F5){
        // game.preventEvent is a interface your app provide to 
        // decide stop event or not
        if (game.preventEvent){
            e.preventdefault()
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @twoyao.. But this would disable the F5 for the whole application. I need to disable F5 only when I am on a particular tab in my application.

Comment: This code only works when my flex application gets loaded and I click F5. But if I perform some actions/clicks on my application and then do F5 the page gets refreshed.