# Pressing F5 does not trigger mousup event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am using the `keyup` event of jQuery. It is working fine with all keys except <kbd>F5</kbd>.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).keyup(function(e){
    alert(e.keyCode); // This is not working always when we press F5
  });
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

I am getting alert on pressing all keys but it is not working fine with <kbd>F5</kbd>. **Sometimes alert is fired with <kbd>F5</kbd> and sometimes not**. I have tried this on Chrome as well as Firefox.

Comment: Maybe because `F5` causes the browser to reload the page? At least it does for me.

Comment: But it must first alert then reload the page.

Comment: Do you want to aboard reloading? Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482059/disable-f5-and-browser-refresh-using-javascript) would help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> reloads the page.

It seems like the page reload is initiated on the `keydown` or `keypress` event, so your `alert` fires **too late**. Depending on how long you press the key, the `mouseup` event is still triggered, and the alert shows briefly, but it doesn't block the reloading process.

If you bind the handler to the `keydown` event as well, page reload is only performed after the the alert is dismissed.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/73644/1/) (click in the empty HTML area first, too ensure it's focused)

Answer (score 0):

If you capture the 'keypress' event, you also block the 't' key. For some reason both the keycode and ASCII keycode are both captured if you use the 'keypress' event (which you can't see in the chrome debugger). The F5 key is '116', but the ASCII keycode for 't' is also 116, so with the 'keypress' event you block F5, but you also block 't' app-wide.

so,Try this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


 $(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
    alert(e.keyCode);  

  });   
 $(document).bind('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 116){
     alert("f5"); 
    }    

  });  
});
</script>
```