# How to access function key to add focus to a control?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In my web application on my master page I have a search box [`<option> </option> list`] for searching pages.

[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGfvz.jpg)

I like to enable this search option on function key press [ f9 ]. How can I do that ?

**Design**

```
<form class="form form-search">
                    <select id="select-templating" data-placeholder="Search " onchange="location = this.value;" class="width300">
                        <option value="">Search</option>
                        <option value="Home.aspx">Home</option>
                        <option value="Modifications.aspx">Modifications</option>
                        <option value="AuthorizationList.aspx">Authorization List</option>
                        <option value="Modifications.aspx">Modifications</option>
                        <option value="AccountClosing.aspx">Account Closing</option>
                        <option value="AccountTransaction.aspx">Account Transaction</option>
                        <option value="CustomerCreation.aspx">Customer Creation</option>
                        <option value="ShareDividendDeclaration.aspx">Share Dividend Declaration</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
```

In the same solution, I used key f2 to redirect to home using `jquery`
function(which is working) :

```
 $(function () {
        $(document).keyup(function (e) {
            var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode);
            switch (key) {

                case 113:
                    window.location.replace("Home.aspx");
                    break;

                default:;
            }
        });
        function navigateUrl(jObj) {
            window.location.href = $(jObj).attr("href");
        }
    });
```

but I don't know how to use f9 key for open search `<option>` control.. Help me please

Comment: So you want to open search dropdown on click of `F9` right?

Comment: yes..! itried to use `$('#select-templating').focus();` its not workng ! am not  familiar with jquery !

Comment: Seems you are using some plugin for `select`, is it?

Comment: yes , its from the html dashboard .

Comment: Yea.. So what plugin?

Comment: select2.min.js plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `open` option of `select2` plugin to open `select` on `F9`:

```
$(document).on('keyup',function(e){
    if(e.which==120){
    $('#select-templating').select2('open');
  }
})
```

**[Here's the Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/xfmgte70/189/)**

Updating your code would be as below:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
     var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode);
     switch (key) {
            case 113:
                window.location.replace("Home.aspx");
                break;
            case 120:
                $('#select-templating').select2('open');
                break;
            default:;
     }
});
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: I have a doubt ! Can we overwrite browser defaulf key ? how can i use f5(default refresh) for other shortcut ( redirect to a page) ?

Comment: @frank.. **[This post helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482059/disable-f5-and-browser-refresh-using-javascript)**.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `focus` method. Example below.

```js
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode);
    switch (key) {

        case 120: {
          $('select').focus();
          break;
        }

        default:;
    }
});
```

```css
select:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
  <option>Opt1</option>
  <option>Opt2</option>
  <option>Opt3</option>
</select>
```

## Edit

You said you tried focus, so maybe try `click` instead of `focus`.

Comment: `$('#select-templating').click`  something like this, on case condition ??

Comment: Yes, don't forget `()` at the end of `click`.

Comment: `$('#select-templating').click();` is also not working :(

Comment: Are you sure it's even doing something? Try some testing stuff like `console.log` when search is clicked or focused.

Comment: `case 120:$('#select-templating').click();//alert("21321321"); break;` i tried to create an alert from f9 , its working bt click is not workng

Comment: That's not what I mean, listen to `click` and `focus` event.

Comment: no solution for this qstn, see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list