# disable location.reload() on specific pages

Tags: javascript

I need to disable reloading on a specific page.

This is a part of some js code from this website:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        setTimeout(function() {
            location.reload();
        }, 1500)
    }
}
```

I really want to stop reloading this page, but i don't know how...

*(I have a Firefox (nightly) browser. I don't want to install Chrome because of an add-on.)*

---

**Second question:**

Can I disable a specific script on the page?

This is the script that I want to disable:

(it's inside `<head>` with an id of `ixqzxn` - the only information I have)

[image]

Comment: why don't you just rewrite the function on those pages? `document.onreadystatechange = function() {}`

Comment: how can i rewrite functions without name since I'm not the owner

Comment: put it in the console and run it

Comment: @Latreso You're not the owner of the website which you want to modify?

Comment: @war10ck probably monkey patching another ones banana

Comment: For personal (browser side) use (improvements, etc.)

Comment: What are you **actually trying to do**.  Why do you want to prevent reloading?  Trying to prevent users from reloading a page is like trying to stop a user from saving an image off of your page: an exercise in futility.

Comment: This might help you to understand about preventing browser refresh. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482059/disable-f5-and-browser-refresh-using-javascript. Regarding your second question , From the DOM using `document.querySelector("script#ixqzxn").remove()` you can remove the script.